# Excel Format float time delay into string

Tags: excel, time, formatting, delay

I have a time delay (in days) column in my excel, for example : **"1,5"**.

I need to display/format it as **"1 day 12 hours"**

I have other numbers with a lot of floating numbers, which means I need months, days,

I need to keep the floating number in background cell, I just want formatting, not replacing.

I cannot found anything about that format, any idea please ? Thanks !

3 => "3 days" ; 2,25 => "2 days 6 hours"
etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom format `d \d\a\y\s h \hou\r\s` if days is not greater than 31.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it seems to work. However, I have many delays with more than 31 days... How to do please ? :)

Comment: @taki I think, then only way is formula or VBA.